# Magento2 cart not finding afterRender function

Tags: magento2

In my magento2 minicart i have `afterRender: loadJsAfterKoRender`

```
 <div class="qty-plus-sign">-</div>
                           <input data-bind="afterRender: loadJsAfterKoRender,attr: {
                           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           'data-item-qty': qty,
                           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                           }, value: qty"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           class="item-qty cart-item-qty qty-box-additions">
                           <div class="qty-plus-sign">+</div>
```

and above the same page in the script tag

```
<script>
define(['jquery', 'uiComponent', 'ko'], function($, Component, ko) {
    'use strict';
    var self;
    return Component.extend({
        loadJsAfterKoRender:function(){
            alert("hi");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

But when the minicart loads i get the error

> knockout.js:3381 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding
>   "afterRender: function(){return loadJsAfterKoRender }" Message:
>   loadJsAfterKoRender is not defined